# Why am I facing error here? Related to signing transactions

Tags: javascript, etherjs

[image: alchemy university]

Why this error occuring?? Can someone direct me to some good resources where I can see what units to provide in the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GasLimit should be a number, not a string.